# Go goroutines leaking

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

Following this post about go-routines leaking, https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2018/11/goroutine-leaks-the-forgotten-sender.html, i tried to solve my leaking code. But adding a buffer to the channel it did not do the trick.

My code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(runtime.NumGoroutine())
    leaking()
    time.Sleep(5)
    fmt.Println(runtime.NumGoroutine())
}

func leaking() {
    errChang := make(chan int, 1)
    go func() {
        xx :=  return666()
        errChang <- xx
    }()
    fmt.Println("hola")
    return

    fmt.Println(<-errChang)
}

func return666() int {
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
    return 6
}
```

My initial code did not use a buffer, leading to the go-routine in the *leaking* function, .. to leak. Following the post i expected that by adding a buffer to the channel, it would have avoided leaking.

Comment: Buffered channel or not I do not see no leaks, can you clarify why you think this code is leaking goroutines? (note: the arguments to time.Sleep are "unfair")

Comment: Nothing is eading from `errChang` (`leaking` returns before it reads from the channel).

Comment: When i run the program, the print statements for the number of goroutines, is 1 2, i would expect the num of goroutines in exit be back to 1. This is why im thinking is leaking.

Comment: @Rakoun for the buffered version you get 1 2 because the goroutine sleeps longer than main, if you give it enough time you'll see it exit and be GCd, i.e. if you change main to sleep for `time.Second*5` for example you'll get 1 1. The unbuffered version actually does have a leak so my initial comment is partly incorrect. The leak is caused by the fact that the `leaking` function returns *before* receiving from the channel so the goroutine gets stuck at `errChang <- xx`, i.e. if you put `<-errChang` above the `return` statement, and increase the sleep time in main, you'll get 1 1 as well.

Comment: @Rakoun here's the [buffered](https://play.golang.com/p/hs5h_wVnxlK) version with a more "fair" sleep time. And here's the [unbuffered](https://play.golang.com/p/kf9tjUvAfiK) version where the `leaking` function receives from the channel before returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here, in the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/rBoiYRcWZc8), is your original code with a few slight modifications:

- the delays are reduced, except for `time.Sleep(5)` which becomes `time.Sleep(time.Second)`;
- a `return` is removed because it becomes unnecessary;
- a `fmt.Println` is commented out, because with both the `return` and the uncommented `fmt.Println`, `go vet` complains about the unreachable `fmt.Println`;
- the channel stored in `errChang` is changed to unbuffered.

When run, its output is:

```
1
hola
2
```

(with a small delay before the `2`), showing that indeed, the anonymous goroutine you started in function `leaking` is still running.

If we [uncomment the commented-out `fmt.Println`](https://play.golang.org/p/YCoTH-40v2m), the output is:

```
1
hola
6
1
```

(with the same slight delay before the final `1`) because we now wait for (and then print) the value computed in `return666` and sent over channel `errChang`.

If we [keep the commented-out `fmt.Println` commented out and make the channel buffered](https://play.golang.org/p/o3eYngdYbfW), the output becomes:

```
1
hola
1
```

as the anonymous goroutine is now able to push its value (6) into the channel.

The channel itself would be garbage collected, along with the single value stored inside it, as there are no remaining references to the channel at this point.  Note, however, that simply making the channel buffered is not always sufficient.  If we [send two values down the channel](https://play.golang.org/p/4Q592mmSNFm), the program returns to printing:

```
1
hola
2
```

as the anonymous goroutine succeeds in putting `6` into the channel but then blocks trying to put `42` in as well.

Comment: for clarification, was the root problem that the return statement made the receive from errChan unreachable?

Comment: @mevets: ... maybe? maybe not exactly? It depends on what you mean by "root problem" and/or "made the receive ... unreachable". Any time you have some goroutine writing to a channel that no one is reading, that's likely to become a problem, and that did happen in the original code, so you could call that the root of the problem. But removing the *write* to the channel would solve it as well.